# How do I chose raws and exclude others for a graphic in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with multiple categories and one of them is the study site. I have many sites but only 3 principle ones. How can I say in Rstudio that I only want to plot those 3 sites sometimes, without having to create a new file with only those sites everytime ?

Adding the fact that I have a line of code, using `facet_warp(vars)` vars=site. So can I add conditions there, using the site's names for it to recognize which to use ?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color =var1,))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(vars(site))+
  geom_point(shape=20, size=4)
```

Comment: Filter your dataframe to the 3 sites you wish to plot before your ggplot2 code.

Comment: I did but then the filter transforms my categories into vectors that are TRUE/FALSE and I can't keep the informations of the other columns associated to the raw of my site name. Is there a specific way to filter so that it doesn't transform automatically into vectors, that for now I can't use in my plot.

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example so that we can help you.